# What is the name of the text to the left of a command (as typed in a terminal) called?

Tags: command-line, bash

I was wondering if there is any name to the leftmost text (after which we type the command) in a Linux terminal.

Like

```
ubuntu@Ubuntu:~$
```

Do we have a name for this?

Comment: This is just called prompt normally

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's called the primary prompt string, set by the shell according to the `PS1` environment variable. This is usually set per user basis, for interactive shells only, (usually) defined in `~/.bashrc` with the default as `\s-\v\$`.

On my system:

```
$ echo "$PS1"
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\W\$
```

and expanded to:

```
username@hostname:pwd$
```

Check the `PROMPTING` section of `man bash` to see what each token does.

Comment: When someone answers me with this quality, I usually wonder how long will it take for me to be at your depth of knowledge. Thanks :-)

Comment: @NabinKhadka Thank you for your kind comments. I am an absolute amateur, still learning every day from the smarter people around me. Everybody was a beginner at some stage, so keep learning and best wishes!!

Comment: @PeterMortensen `PS` prompts are POSIX.

Comment: `PS1`, `PS2`, and `PS4` are POSIX. `PS3` is used by the non-POSIX `select` command, and `bash` recently introduced a `PS0` prompt to display *after* reading a command but before actually executing it.

Comment: @chepner Too much generalization from my side (on popular prompts) :/

Answer (score 0):

The prompt. There are ways of editing what it shows, e.g. see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization). Most of these personalizations can be used with other shells e.g. [ZSH](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php), or [KSH](http://francesco-cek.com/setting-a-custom-prompt-in-ksh-2/). [TCSH](http://www.nparikh.org/unix/prompt.php) may act a little differently, but I am less familiar with it.